# Как обратиться по индексу к клонированному элементу в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть в том, что я хочу в коллекции 'fields' заменить у некоторых элементов атрибут 'name'.

Но по индексу [i] я почему то не могу обратиться, выдает ошибку.

```
  var fields = $('.fieldset').clone();
  for (var i = index; i < length; i++) 
  {
     fields[i].find('input.field-header').attr('name', 'MyName');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что если обращаться к `jquery-объекту` по индексу, то возвращается `js-объект` у которого нет метода `find`  попробуйте воспользоваться методом `eq`

```
fields.eq(i).find('input.field-header').attr('name', 'MyName');
```

еще можно так

```
fields.each(function () {
  $(this).find('input.field-header').attr('name', 'MyName');
})
```